# Resize partition with encrypted home?

Tags: partitioning, encryption, gparted

I'm in a need for a free unallocated space (need Win install because of work) and I do have a question which I couln't answer myself from what I've managed to find on Google.

I do have these two main partitions:

/ [40GB] root partition

/home/ [400GB] home partition

I'm the single user on my laptop and my home folder (not the whole partition) is encrypted. **The question is: Is it safe to resize the /home/ partition without any errors using gparted?**

Answer (score 1):

If the whole partition were encrypted, resizing would be complicated, but that's not the case. It's perfectly safe to resize it.